# Gradle sync failed: No value with key 'distributionUrl' specified in wrapper properties file

Tags: android, kotlin, build, build.gradle

When I try to create a new project (in Kotlin/Java) this error occours. Anyone to help me with this?

> Gradle sync failed: Could not load wrapper properties from
> 'C:\Users\gabri\OneDrive\Documentos\TO\MyApplication\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
> No value with key 'distributionUrl' specified in wrapper properties
> file
> 'C:\Users\gabri\OneDrive\Documentos\TO\MyApplication\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from
> 'C:\Users\gabri\OneDrive\Documentos\TO\MyApplication\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
> at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor. (WrapperExecutor.java:61) at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forProjectDirectory(WrapperExecutor.java:38)
> at
> org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory.getDefaultDistribution(DistributionFactory.java:62)
> at
> org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultGradleConnector.connect(DefaultGradleConnector.java:137)
> at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.getConnection(GradleExecutionHelper.java:502)
> at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:273)
> at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:125)
> at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:60)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:35)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:57)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:35)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:44)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:146)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:132)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:544)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:392)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:150)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:392)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:660)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:888)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.lambda$run$0(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
> at
> com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: No value with key 'distributionUrl'
> specified in wrapper properties file
> 'C:\Users\gabri\OneDrive\Documentos\TO\MyApplication\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.reportMissingProperty(WrapperExecutor.java:135)
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:78)
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExecutor.java:67)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor. (WrapperExecutor.java:54) ...
> 34 more Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (56 ms)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The ANDROID_HOME variable was not set correctly on the computer**

Answer (score 1):

It happpens sometimes that files dont sync well and stuff.

Try these:

1. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Sync project with Gradle Files
2. Go to Build -> Clean Project -> Rebuild Project.

If this wont work then It seems like the distributionUrl is missing in your gradle-wrapper.properties of your project. gradle-wrapper.properties looks like as follows. check your path and add distributionUrl inside gradle-wrapper.properties file

Possible solution for this is to go to File -> Settings. Under Settings window choose Build,Execution, Deployment. Then under build tools choose Gradle. Click on use local gradle Distribution. Change gradle home by browsing gradle location eg. ... /gradle/gradle-2.10

Comment: where is the /gradle/gradle-2.10? Inside the new project or in Android directory?